# How to test if child process stdout/stderr is inherited?

Tags: java, linux

Consider the following method:

```
Process execProcess(String... command) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
    pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
    return pb.start();
}
```

I want to write a test for `execProcess()` so as to test if the method does indeed output a process that inherits the stdout/stderr of the current process. Something like this is what I'd like:

```
@Test
public void testProcessFDInheritance() {
    Process p = execProcess("echo", "test thing");
    /*
      Check current process' stdout to see if p outputted "test thing"
    */
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `p.getErrorStream() == System.err` ? If that doesn't work, then I don't know if there is a way to do this from java.

Comment: I believe separate parent and child processes have newly instantiated PrintStream objects for out/err so this doesn't work I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original program's stdout is owned by whatever process launched it - which could be the terminal, or some file redirection, or a pipe to another process.

Since you don't have control over your own stdout, the only way to solve this problem is to launch your original executable in a wrapper process. The wrapper process can then perform the checks to determine if it saw a particular output.

`Wrapper` launches `original`, `original` launches `echo`. `echo` prints to its stdout that it shares with `original`, `wrapper` reads from `original's` stdout and sees `"test thing"`.